# Does dependency injection really matters in iOS Application development?

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection

I am looking at '**Cleanse**' and '**Swinject**' from past two days. Can anyone tell me or explain me the real use of Dependency injection and How it Help us in the iOS app development?.

I was really confused about which part of my application (classes) I need to apply dependancy injection and which not. I think it is making my code very complex.

Comment: Dependency Injection allows you to "stub" or "mock" a lot of the parameters you pass to functions/classes etc. This makes your code a lot more "testable" as you can mock out an API to a local file etc. This can be invaluable with unit testing which in turn gives you more confidence about the code you are writing and releasing

Comment: For a great introduction on Dependency Injection, read [this excerpt](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-writing-maintainable-loosely-coupled-code/) from [Dependency Injection PP&P](https://manning.com/seemann2).

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand why is his answer downvoted, this is a fellow developer who tries to understand how Dependency Injection works and wants help, not discouragement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency injection is nothing more than injecting dependencies into an object instead of tasking the object with the responsibility of creating its dependencies.

Example:

```
class UserViewModel {
     var User = User?
}

let UserViewModel = UserViewModel()
let User = User()
UserViewModel.User = User
```

**Types of dependency Injection:**

- dependency injection through an initializer (initializer injection)
- dependency injection using properties (property injection)
- dependency injection in methods (method injection)

**Benefits we will get:**

> - transparency

By injecting the dependencies of an object, the responsibilities and requirements of a class or structure become more clear and transparent. By injecting a User into a UserViewModel, we understand that the UserViewModel depends on the User.

> - Improve testability

Unit testing is much easier with dependency injection. Dependency injection allows developers to replace an object's dependencies with mock objects, which makes isolating behavior and setting up unit tests easier and less complicated.

> - Seperation of Concerns

Dependency injection allows us to understand our code in a much clearer way and separates our concerns. When we use dependency injection, we can see that our objects are responsible for managing and handling the given dependency. Following one of the examples above, our UserViewModel is responsible for managing and handling our library object.

> - Loose coupling

The example of the UserViewModel class illustrated how the use of protocols and dependency injection can reduce coupling in a project. Protocols are incredibly useful and versatile in Swift. The example we discussed is a scenario in which protocols really shine.

Comment: I read this somewhere. But it is not actual dependency Injection. I looked some tutorials related to Dependency Injection. I will share them with you and please look into it. https://github.com/square/Cleanse/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: Cleanse and Swinject are two dependancy injection management tools we have for Swift

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia Doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection),

> In software engineering, dependency injection is a technique whereby one object (or static method) supplies the dependencies of another object. A dependency is an object that can be used (a service).

**And In simple terms**,

> When class A uses some functionality of class B, then its said that class A has a dependency of class B.

**Or**

> Transferring the task of creating the object to someone else and directly using the dependency is called dependency injection.

**Diagramatically :**

> [image]

---

> 1. I was really confused about which part of my application (classes) I need to apply dependancy injection and which not.

You almost uses this widely but in android this word well known. Let's look an example,

Let's assume we have two controller, masterVC and detailVC. detailVC shows data in details what data is selected in masterVC. Now you need to pass selected data (ID, key) from masterVC to detailVC. For this, you need to access the detailVC method or variable in masterVC like below,

```
let objDetailVC = DetailVC() // Init of class
objDetailVC.ID = selectedID
// push controller
```

Now, detailVC is depended on ID, it is called **dependency injection** (**DI**).

> 2. I think it is making my code very complex.

No, It creates your project more dynamic. Currently I managed 5 controller in a single controller with the help of MVC structure and dependency injection. Project is very smooth, well managed, high code reusability.

So it all upto you how you manage the code.

---

> Edit

You can use DI like above example or you can create method in detailVC and treat it like abstraction.

For better details refer : [Cocoacast: Nuts and Bolts of Dependency Injection in Swift](https://cocoacasts.com/nuts-and-bolts-of-dependency-injection-in-swift)

Comment: Which framework you are using for DI?  I didn't see any library in your answer. and to my knowledge, the example you gave about DetailVC() and objDetailVC.ID = selectID is a very common approach and it is no way related to Dependency Injection.

Comment: Cleanse and Swinject are two dependancy injection management tools we have for Swift. Please look into them

Comment: @dahiya_boy Your diagram explaining the dependency has made it very clear to me. Would be wonderful if you could show a diagram with the same 2 classes, but now with dependency injection shown. Because I still cannot see how to fix the problem when I have a class A that uses/needs/depends on methods in class B.